# contamination? what's this?

Tags: fermentation, contamination

I brewed a hoppy red ale on Tuesday and pitched some washed wyeast 1084 into it that evening. I had an og of 1.070 and went ahead and put a blowoff tube on the fermenting bucket in case I had a huge krausen. I did not see any fermentation bubbles, and later realized that the seal was not as tight as I thought it was between the tube and bucket lid. Today put in a regular airlock and noticed a strange green scaley looking growth on the top of my beer. Is this some sort of contamination? A picture is attatched...!  I'm new to the site so i can't post the picture on here. However, you can check out my HBT post with the pic here http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f163/contamination-whats-305419/
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I added the picture. It's a good example of krausen for other beginners to see.

Comment: [How do I upload an image to a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) on Meta provides step by step guide to inserting images.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal. It's [krausen](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter8-2-2.html) - bits of yeast, hop particles and oils, trub and proteins floating on top of the beer - and a sign of healthy fermentation.

- [Fermentation](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter8-2-2.html), How to brew, J. Palmer

Comment: Looks like a "mostly done" krausen. The green ring on the sides of the bucket is a high water mark, showing how tall the krausen was at its peak.

Comment: I agree Tobias - at first glance I thought the white parts (the bucket) was white from the krausen. Then it would have been a new krausen, but this here has almost all fallen back in, so it's a "I'm pretty much done, but leave me alone for a bit to condition" krausen.